# Is there some sort of API or tool to programmatically navigate Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, selenium, automated-tests, ui-automation, sikuli

I have been trying to find some sort of tool to help me with my automation efforts. What I am trying to do is navigate through Google Maps. For example, on the search box, I type Napa,CA. Let's say I want to simulate, navigating west of Napa, and then do a couple of zooms.

So far I have something hacked with Sikuli and Selenium, but I am not 100% confident about this solution. Basically, I use different images next to Napa to help me navigate to the desired location and use Selenium to find the zoom in and out elements.

Is there such thing or am I being delusional?

Comment: considering that Google maps does not use any third party software like Flash, or Silverlight, i think you're golden.  not sure if there is anything out there though

Comment: Why do you want to test Google maps?

Comment: not testing Google maps per say, but more of a verification process for our tool

Comment: If you don't mind, would you like to expand a bit on what your tool does and what it is that you'd like to test - and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an API: https://developers.google.com/maps/

You probably want the web API.  It's JavaScript, so that may not work for you depending on what you're trying to accomplish, but you could be using the [`panBy` and `setZoom`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) methods to move the map around.